# How to display recent posts on home page with title, post date, author and a featured images as background for thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress, post

I am looking to display x (undecided) number of recent posts (no more than 5) on my home page banner. For each post, I would like to display the title, post date, author and a featured images as background for thumbnail of the content. I was wondering what the WordPress function is to get this. I would also like to custom format the HTML. The closest I have gotten is looks like this

```
<!-- Post carousel -->
            <div class="cs-post-carousel-layout">
                <div class="cs-container swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <?php

    // define query arguments
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 8, // your 'x' goes here
        'nopaging' => true
        // possibly more arguments here
    );

    // set up new query
    $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // loop through found posts
    while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) : $tyler_query->the_post();
                        //Post item -->
                        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">'.
                            '<div class="cs-post-item">'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-category-icon">'.
                                    '<a href="'.
                                    get_permalink().
                                    '"></i></a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-thumb">'.
                                    '<a href="post_standard.html"><img src="demo/carousel/1.jpg" alt="UniqMag"></a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div class="cs-post-inner">'.
                                    '<h3><a href="'.
                                    get_permalink().
                                    '">'.
                                    get_the_title().
                                    '</a></h3>'.
                                    //'<div class="cs-post-meta cs-clearfix">'.
                                       // '<span class="cs-post-meta-author"><a href="post_standard.html">J. Doe</a></span>'.
                                       // '<span class="cs-post-meta-date">Sep 19, 2015</span>'.
                                    //'</div>'.
                                '</div>'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>';
                        endwhile;

    // reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For date you can use [get_the_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) function of wordpress. For author [get_the_author()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author) function of wordpress, and for the thumbnail, [the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) function